# Does this image means SSLv3 is enabled?

Tags: openssl

[image]

I see that there is TLSv1/SSLv3, however the protocol used is TLSv1.2.

Any advice is warming welcome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: To answer your question, use [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) to audit the server's configuration, and ensure expected protocols are enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 1):

THIS PARTICULAR TEST DOESN'T SHOW SSLv3. The `New, <ver> Cipher is` line is about the version of OpenSSL's internal cipher description, which is the same for SSLv3 and all versions of TLS (to date), and different only from SSLv2 (which nobody should be using today, but OpenSSL still has the code to support unless a build option is specified). As you correctly identified, the value in `Protocol:` is the protocol version actually negotiated.

BUT THIS DOESN'T PROVE SSLv3 IS DISABLED. A server can support multiple protocol versions and choose one for each connection, preferably and usually the highest available, and most servers do. `openssl s_client` by default offers *up to* TLSv1.2, and a server capable of TLSv1.2 will agree to that, as the server in this case did. But if a client **offers** a lower version the server can either agree to it or reject it. POODLE and similar attacks work by tricking the client into offering SSLv3 to which the server agrees. So if you want to test for this vulnerability, try `s_client` with `-ssl3` and see whether *that* produces a session or not.